# Having an issue with a simple select, where statement

Tags: mysql, sql, select, where-clause

I'm new to SQL and cant seem to get my head around using a `WHERE` clause on only part of the statement. For example, (written basically)

```
SELECT Forename, Surname, Organisation 
FROM Client table

SELECT Renewal day AND Renewal month AS Renewal date 
FROM Client table
WHERE Renewal day <> 0
```

I need this all to be one statement but also so that the where clause isn't effecting the Forename, Surname  and Organisation fields. E.g The table would be full of clients but the renewal date column will only display a date for clients that have one. Thanks

Comment: Can you provide some example data and what you are actually looking to get from the query?

Comment: It would have all of the clients data (Forename, Surname, organisation) but only include the renewal date for those that have one

Comment: If your columns have spaces in their names, which is nothing but a nuisance and should be avoided, you'll need to enclose them with backticks. `SELECT \`Renewal day\` ...`

Comment: Store the renewal date/datetime as a single column.

Comment: I need to not have the where clause effect the other columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Forename, Surname, Organisation, IF(Renewal day <> 0, Renewal day AND Renewal month, '') as Renewal
FROM Client table
```

Should do the trick. This won't run straight away as the AND statement in the IF won't be liked, though you could use:

```
IF(Renewal day <> 0, CONCAT(Renewal day,Renewal month), '') as Renewal
```

or

```
IF(Renewal day <> 0, Renewal day) as renewDay, IF(Renewal day <> 0, Renewal month, '') as renewMonth
```

to have 2 separate fields.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing is to store the renewal date as a date and allow nulls, then you just do:

```
SELECT Forename, Surname, Organization, RenewalDate 
FROM Client
```